# Lua: Fetch string from webpage

Tags: http, lua, fetch

I'm learning Lua to augment my conky script, and one of the things I want to do is take information from this website (www.talks.cam.ac.uk), specifically the date and title of each lecture, and assign them to strings.

I've got Lua 5.2 installed, as well as Lua Socket, and I've tried the following code:

```
local http=require'socket.http'
body,c,l,h = http.request('http://www.talks.cam.ac.uk')
```

but it doesn't work, as I get this message:

```
stack traceback:
stdin:1: in main chunk
[C]: in ?
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your example does work here. Is this a full traceback message ?

Comment: @DavidUnric That is the full traceback message. I wasn't aware that it was working, because when I try `print(body)` or any of the other three variables, I get `nil` as an output.

Comment: Works fine here.
body is the content and c is the response status.
if c is nil, socket might be missing?

Comment: @das I installed lua-socket and lua-socket-dev from the terminal using apt-get.

Comment: @das Also if I `print(require'socket.http')` I get `table: 0x1b16520` as an output, which suggests to me that socket is working in some capacity.

Comment: Where did you get a Lua 5.2 version of LuaSocket?

Comment: @Mud I installed Lua 5.2 `sudo apt-get install Lua5.2`, but LuaSocket didn't show any version dependency `sudo apt-get install lua-socket`.

Comment: Every Lua module necessarily *has* a version dependency, whether it says so or not. I have no idea where apt-get pulls from, so it's possible somebody has built a version of LuaSocket for 5.2, but the binary on the LuaSocket webpage is for [5.1](http://w3.impa.br/~diego/software/luasocket/home.html#download). You might want to try downloading Lua 5.1, just to rule that out as the source of your problem.

Comment: @Mud I installed Lua 5.1, and got the same issues when running the above script. I also then uninstalled, just to be sure I was running on Lua 5.1, and the issue remained.

Comment: @Mud apparently the version of Socket I have is LuaSocket 3.0-rc1